# Journey: Send Email to Sales Team using Filtered Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, automation

I have a form submission Data Extension in Marketing Cloud that creates a Filtered Data Extension to pull in a list of leads that need to alert my sales team. The filtered data extension pulls in a group email address for the sales team using a hidden field on the form, and this is the subscriberkey in the DE. The lead's email is a text field in the data extension.

I created a journey that evaluates the filtered data extension every hour to qualify anyone NEW in the data extension, populates an alert email with the submission information, and sends that email to the group sales email address.

However, when I first turned on the DE, my settings were to allow for re-entry anytime, since each record in the filtered DE has the same email address (salesemail) and I didn't want it to dedup. This caused all form submissions to send every time the DE was evaluated. I changed the settings to NOT allow re-entry at all, and now only one record has qualified (I'm guessing this is is now a dedup issue).

Anyone had to solve for this in the past? Obviously, we are not connected to CRM using the connector, which is why I'm looking for a work around.

**The goal is to get an alert email to the sales team group email address every time someone fills out a smart capture form on a cloudpage.**

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather not use a journey at all, but use an hourly automation instead.
Your automation could have three steps:

1. Create a SQL query activity that will check the conditions of the filtered DE. Create a Boolean field in Target DE, 'Email_Sent'. Default Value should be 'N'.
   Include a condition in the SQL: `where Email_Sent = 'N'`
   Data Action: Should be Add and Update.(Not overwrite)
2. Send the email.
3. Update the value of the records as 'Y' for all the records using SQL. The data action should update.

When next time, the automation runs, it will not pull the records where the email is already sent.

Consider the primary key to be a composite key - It should be the sales email address + lead email address. So that update works fine

Comment: This is great @Swati thank you - a follow up question if you don't mind? The Filtered DE is just pulling out records that qualify for sales from the form submission DE (many forms pushing to one DE) so yes, it's possible to write the conditions straight into SQL. Unfortunately, I don't have a submission date value in my Data Extensions. Is there a way to write the SQL without looking at a date value? If I try to add a field to the DE now, I'm going to lose a lot of work - cloud page and journey issues/logic issues seem to result and have happened many times already

Comment: Edited my answer above

Comment: As a good practice, I would encourage you to have submission date in future in the DE :)

Comment: Absolutely! thank you for the direction here @swati! :)